# How to handling null, blank or no Element found issues in Linq-To-Xml?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I am getting a warning about a possible `system.NullReferenceException` where the code is `el.Attribute("id").Value` in the query below. How do I change this query to handle such a possibility?

```
var RentAssumptionPreScreen = xdoc.Descendants("Rent")
    .Single(el => el.Attribute("id").Value == "11162")
    .Parent.Descendants("Value").Single().Value;
```

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Comment: What is giving you the warning?

Comment: Try this `Single(el => el.Attribute("id")?.Value == "11162")`

Comment: There is a blue squiggly line under the line mentioned above. When I hover over that line in VB is when it reads the `Possible system.NullReferenceException`. I decided to test this issue by making the value return null. I have edited my code above to show the error.

Comment: You could use el.Attribute("id")?.Value, which would handle null. If "id" being blank shouldn't be an issue for that predicate to run. No Element found could be an issue if xdoc has no children meaning Single has no attributes to act on. You could use FirstOrDefault instead and then use the '?' operator again in case no element matches the query.

Comment: I had already tried `Single(el => el.Attribute("id")?.Value == "11162")` but still get same error.

Comment: danielm could you show me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var RentAssumptionPreScreen = xdoc.Descendants("Rent")
    .FirstOrDefault(el => el.Attribute("id")?.Value == "11162")?
    .Parent.Descendants("Value").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```